# Number of closed regions created by a path

Tags: algorithm, graph, coordinates, graph-algorithm, minimization

Given a path P described by a list of positions in the xy-plane that are each connected by edges, compute the least number of edges that have to be removed from P such that P does not close off any regions in the xy-plane (i.e., it should be possible to go from any point to any other point). Every position will have integer coordinates, and each position will be one unit left, right, up, or down from the previous one.

For example, if `P = {[0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [1,0], [0,0]}`, then the path is a square starting and ending at (0,0). Any 1 of the 4 edges of the square could be removed, so the answer is 1.

Note that the same edge can be drawn twice. That is, if `P = {[0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [1,0], [0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [1,0], [0,0]}`, the answer would be 2, because now each side of the square has 2 edges, so at least 2 edges would have to be removed to "free" the square.

I've tried a naive approach where if any position is visited twice, there could be an enclosed region (not always, but my program relies on this assumption), so I add 1 to the minimum number of edges removed. In general if a vertex is visited N times I add N-1 to the number of edges removed. However, if, for example, `P = {[0,0], [0,1], [0,0]}`, there is no enclosed region whereas my program would think there is. Another case of where it breaks down: if `P = {[0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [1,0], [0,0], [1,0]}`, my program would output 2 (since (0,0) and (0,1) are each visited twice), whereas the correct answer is 1, since we can just remove any of the other three sides of the square.

It seems that there are two primary subtasks to solve this problem: first, given the path, figure out which positions are enclosed (i.e., figure out the regions that the path splits the graph into); second, use knowledge of the regions to identify which edges must be removed to prevent enclosures.

Any hints, pseudocode, or code would be appreciated.

**Source**: Princeton's advanced undergraduate class on algorithms.

Comment: What's the maximum number of points ?

Comment: @saadtaame The path will contain at most 1000 entries. So, 1000 edges (with multiplicity).

Comment: Adding more details might help. Are the coordinates integers? Where did you encounter this problem ?

Comment: Wild hunch with no thought: I wonder if it's sufficient to merge multiple edges as @saadtaame said, so each merged edge has a weight equal to the number of repeats. Then find a maximum spanning tree in the remaining graph. The edges not in the tree would be the ones to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas that might help. I'm going to assume that you have `n` points.

You could first insert all of the edges in a set `S` so that duplicate edges are removed:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    S.insert( {min(p[i], p[i+1), max(p[i], p[i+1])} );
```

Now iterate over the edges again and build a graph. Then find the longest simple path in this graph.

The resulting graph is bipartite (if a cycle exists it must have even length). This piece of information might help as well.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the connection between the longest path and enclosed regions? Also, we do care about duplicate edges, since if a boundary has duplicated, because if every edge on a closed boundary is duplicated then two edges need to be removed, etc.

Comment: @user5802336 A simple path won't have cycles in it. The longest one because that will minimize the number of edges that you'll have to remove. But then longest path is NP-Hard except if your graph is "special".

Comment: The vertices are given in the order they are traversed, so isn't that the longest path?

Comment: Longest SIMPLE path. It should not have cycles.

Comment: Any other insights given that the steps are unit length? Or anything else towards a solution?

Comment: Nodes have degree at most 4. Other than that I can't find something useful. If you are studying this maybe you can give context or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flood-fill algorithm to find the contiguous regions of the plane created by the path. One of these regions is infinite but it's easy to compute the perimeter with a scanline sweep, and that will limit the total size to be no worse than quadratic in the length of the path. If the path length is less than 1,000 then quadratic is acceptable. (**Edit:** I later realized that since it is only necessary to identify the regions adjacent to edges of the line, you can do this computation by sorting the segments and then applying a scanline sweep, resulting in O(n log n) time complexity.)

Every edge in the path is between two regions (or is irrelevant because the squares on either side are the same region). For the relevant edges, you can count repetitions and then find the minimum cost boundary between any pair of adjacent regions. All that is linear once you've identified the region id of each square.

Now you have a weighted graph. Construct a minimum spanning tree. That should be precisely the minimum collection of edges which need to be removed.

There may well be a cleverer solution. The flood-fill strikes me as brute-force and naive, but it's the best I can do in ten minutes.

Good luck.

Comment: More implementations details would be helpful. Specifically: (1) Can you explain in more detail how we find the regions with a flood-fill? (2) I don't understand your bit on relevant/irrelevant edges. (3) What is the structure (i.e. elements) of the graph?

Comment: 1. Id=0; for each square in floodfill, set region_id(square) to id; id+=1; find an unmarked square and repeat.

Comment: 2. Each edge has two adjacent squares. If they are in the same region, the edge does not separate them and can be ignored. It is irrelevant.

Comment: 3. Each region (graph node) has an id. Iterating over uniquified edges produces a weighted adjacency list. (If the graph edge is already present, change the weight if the new one is smaller.) Adjacency lists are a common graph datastructure, and I'm sure you can come up with a minimim spanning tree algorithm which uses them.

Comment: When you refer to a "square", what do you mean? Do you mean an xy-position on the coordinate plane?

Also, do you mind providing pseudocode for (3)? I still don't understand the approach.

Comment: Yes, a square on the plane. And I'm not going to write MST for you. It's in Sedgwick or whatever other text you use.